# Use Stream as PostgresSQL parameter in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

Is there a way to pass a Stream as a sql parameter to insert a query into a Postgres bytea/jsonb column using .NET? As I already have a Stream and those column types are binary types, I'm trying to pass it to query instead of reading it to byte[]/string and then passing it.

Like in [this sample from SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support#sample----streaming-to-sql-server) or in [this sample using java's JDBC driver](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-binary-data.html).

I've tried something like this:

```cs
public static async Task Insert(NpgsqlConnection connection, Guid id, Stream payload)
{
    string commandText = $"INSERT INTO some_table (id, payload, occurred_on) " +
    $"VALUES (@id, @payload, @occurred_on)";
    await using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("payload", payload);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("occurred_on", DateTime.Now);

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

But it has thrown an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Can't write CLR type System.IO.MemoryStream with handler type ByteaHandler

I found there is https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#raw-binary-copy, but I'd like to insert a single row with multiple columns, one of which is passed as a Stream, and if I'm correct, it is not possible with it.

Comment: Looks like this just got added to NpgSql https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/pull/4517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Charlieface pointed out, from npgsql version 7.0 (currently in preview; I tested it on version `7.0.0-preview.7`), it will be possible to pass a `Stream` as a parameter to the `bytea` column.

You just have to pass it like any other type. The only exception is when the `Stream` is not seekable, then it is required to provide its size in `DbParameter.Size` property.

```cs
public static async Task Insert(NpgsqlConnection connection, Guid id, Stream payload)
{
    string commandText = $"INSERT INTO some_table (id, payload, occurred_on) " +
    $"VALUES (@id, @payload, @occurred_on)";
    await using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("payload", payload);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("occurred_on", DateTime.Now);

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Postgres does not support streaming for such query.
As result npgsql library unable to handle the case. See discussion [Write parameter from streams/readers](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/550).